# MyISAM queries are always at least 100ms

Tags: mysql, mariadb, myisam, pt-query-digest

I have some old software that use MyISAM tables on Mariadb 10.6

When I am checking query digest from pt-query-digest Percona Toolkit, I always see execution time from 100ms.

What can be wrong here?

Innodb tables show lower time.

This one is for simple count(*) query over small table(under 30k records):

```
# Query 5: 0.69 QPS, 0.17x concurrency, ID 0x761C0D5EAEC0B8FBB64279CF7F7B2727 at byte 0
# This item is included in the report because it matches --limit.
# Scores: V/M = 0.05
# Time range: 2024-02-07T15:00:14 to 2024-02-07T15:19:49
# Attribute    pct   total     min     max     avg     95%  stddev  median
# ============ === ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= =======
# Count          2     807
# Exec time      4    200s   100ms   509ms   248ms   393ms   116ms   293ms
# Lock time      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# Query size     1  89.05k     113     113     113     113       0     113
# id             4  10.18G  12.57M  13.30M  12.92M  13.08M 278.63k  12.46M
# String:
# Databases    asterisk
# Hosts        45.77.125.169:37888 (7/0%)... 266 more
# Users        cron
# Query_time distribution
#   1us
#  10us
# 100us
#   1ms
#  10ms
# 100ms  ################################################################
#    1s
#  10s+
# Tables
#    SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `asterisk` LIKE 'vicidial_carrier_log'\G
#    SHOW CREATE TABLE `asterisk`.`vicidial_carrier_log`\G
# EXPLAIN /*!50100 PARTITIONS*/
SELECT dialstatus,count(*) from vicidial_carrier_log where call_date >= "2024-02-06 15:11:04" group by dialstatus\G
```

It does not matter how many rows in table and what is real query.

The question is:

Why **MINIMUM** value is always 100ms, not why maximum sometimes over 3s. Maximum is because of concurrent locks.

The command line is :

```
/usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/pt-query-digest --processlist h=127.0.0.1,u=queryprofiler,p=mqueryprofiler --run-time=598s --interval 0.03
```

Comment: What's wrong is using MyISAM. InnoDB is way easier to tune. Does your software really care what engine is used? An `ALTER TABLE` on small tables doesn't take that long, assuming the real problem here isn't ancient hardware, like some awful RAID system on HDDs.

Comment: That is vicidial. It just locks with InnoDB and nobody want spend time digging that old code for find sources of locks. It has many unrelated Perl and PHP scripts with over 1mln lines of code.

Comment: Yes, I know that innodb is better and I know how to tune it. I am not asking how to migrate to innodb.

Comment: Querying an in-memory index (InnoDB) is always faster than reading an disk-stored heap (MyISAM). Do you have an index in the table?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename` should be really fast in MyISAM, it just looks it up in the metadata. It's slow in InnoDB because the row count is not kept up-to-date. Is the `SELECT COUNT(*)` query more complicated than that?

Comment: Changing engines shouldn't have any impact on the scripts.

Comment: Yes, I understand that Innodb is faster. Yes, I know that it should not affect script. Yes, I also know that it DOES. http://www.vicidial.org/VICIDIALforum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=27342

Comment: please show the actual query

Comment: "Yes, I understand that Innodb is faster..." -- No. InnoDB is faster **for this specific query**. Other queries may show different results. Bottom line: optimize based on the queries you need. Show us the queries you need to be optimized.

Comment: All queries are affected.  At least how digest show it. Query is simple lookup for varchar index, index is in key cache.

Comment: For me it looks like some type of lock, but why it is ALWAYS 100ms?

Comment: @Barmar  *Changing engines shouldn't have any impact on the scripts*, using ViciDial it does. See my question on https://www.vicidial.org/VICIDIALforum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=41633 .

Comment: @arheops does this affect your running system ? In my case I take care for let's say the main tables such as `vicidial_log`,`call_log`,`recording_log`,`vicidial_closer_log` to never be locked

Comment: Yes, it is vicibox running 120 agents. But it show those 100ms minimum even when load is minimal and even for small tables like vicidial_manager. I virtually see no lines in digest with less than 100ms. And disk is NVME

Comment: @ErgestBasha I'm not familiar with Vicidial, I just meant that it shouldn't require recoding queries in the scripts.

Comment: @Barmar it use multiple scripts(really alot of ) on multiple servers, non of that writed with transactions or locks in mind and it prevent race conditions only by table level lock. So without major(or even full) rewrite it is not possible to migrate to Innodb. If that would be possible sure I first tried to switch.

Comment: What is the result of this query: `SELECT @@long_query_time;`?

Comment: long query time is 1 sec. This one is between 100 and 300 MILLIseconds,they not go to long query log.

Comment: Look at `ANALYZE EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ... ` output and or break it down with [SHOW PROFILE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-profile/).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there were *no* indexes on your small 30K-row MyISAM table.  Since the row count is [I think] stored in the `.MYI` file that does not exist, it must read the data to count the rows.

InnoDB is slower than MyISAM for virtually all simple `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl`.

It may be that some other activity has a `LOCK` on the table.  This can slow down many operations.  (InnoDB allows concurrent access to a table, hence faster in many situations.)

Why only 100ms?  Was `long_query_time` set to 0.1 (seconds)?  If so, maybe only a few `SELECTs` happened to barely reach 100ms.  How many times was the `COUNT` run?

The Query_cache, if in effect adds wrinkles to this discussion.  See *both* `query_cache_type` and `query_cache_size`.

Neither data nor indexes are "kept in memory" for either MyISAM or InnoDB.  In all combinations the bytes are *cached* in a manner akin to "least recently used".  (With sufficient RAM, all will stay cached in ram.)

**More**

This is *not* a simple `COUNT(*)`:

```
SELECT  dialstatus, count(*)
    from  vicidial_carrier_log
    where  call_date >= "2024-02-06 15:11:04"
    group by  dialstatus;
```

But it can be optimized (for either MyISAM or InnoDB) with the addition of

```
INDEX(dialstatus, call_date),
INDEX(call_date, dialstatus)
```

The Optimizer will pick the index that will work better with the distribution of data relative to that particular date.

Comment: there are indexes, indexes are used and key_cache usage is 10%. The problem is MINIMUM always at 100ms.  EXACTLY 100ms

Comment: Thats what I am asking. WHY minimum ALWAYS at round 100ms?

Comment: Query cache is not an option here, it has issues with concurrent cores and those tables have like 50% write, so it will be not valid most of the time.

Comment: See what happens with `long_query_time = 0.05`

Comment: Original was simple count. But no diff actually for both. Just no any more original in digest, I have rewrite that part. For long_query_time like that I will have log full of queries, I have like 50QPS with 10+ms.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have found the issue

The MyISAM table need command be like

```
pt-query-digest --interval 0.05
```

If you want 50ms minimum. Maybe that bug, maybe it is feature, but it is like that.

Comment: Given the contents of the question, it is unlikely somebody would be able to have realized the issue was with the report generation tool you were using, since you did not mention the tool.  It would be helpful if you added the name of this reporting tool to the question text and tags

Comment: Sure, I also did not realize it. And even more, google say nothing, AI say nothing, on innodb tables it works without this param. It is pt-query-digest by Percona, from distro package.

Comment: `long_query_time` controls what is captured; `pt-query-digest` won't see anything that was not captured.

Comment: @RickJames That's not quite true.  Although the tool can analyze data from the slow query log, it states in its man page:  "It can analyze queries from MySQL slow, general, and binary logs. (Binary logs must first be converted to text, see --type). It can also use SHOW PROCESSLIST and MySQL protocol data from tcpdump"  So without seeing the command line being executed to render the report (and the relevant settings files, if any), we can't know what source is being used for the query list.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler - Good point.  However, the general log is a disk hog and must be used with caution.  The binary log does not have `SELECTs`, which seems to be the OP's use case, and might require `binlog_format=STATEMENT`.  For the processlist, I hope it uses `FULL`.

Comment: That is compleatly not true. It do capture without slow log at all. It makes SHOW PROCESSLIST. Binlog and general log are disabled.